# Python PIL drawing text and multiline text - use of anchor argument

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Is the anchor argument obsolete or is it for future use? It is currently just passed between the two functions: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/ImageDraw.py#L244 I'd like to give the lower left corner of the text bounding box as a reference point. Thought anchor would be just for that.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it's never been implemented. I checked the [old PIL source code](https://github.com/hugovk/PIL/blame/97c6b8d0d89a14721c756e4a97312fa04bde24ac/PIL/ImageDraw.py#L255), dating from around 1999, and it's similarly not used.